# How to deal with unused array space in C

Tags: c, arrays, null

Im working on a Caesar cipher and everything seems to be working fine, except that at the end of my sentences I get a whole bunch of non alpha numerical gibberish added on. Im almost positive this is due to having extra array space, but I need to allow the user to input at 100 characters and C doesn't seem to have an equivalent of an arraylist so I'm not sure how to go about getting rid of this problem.  here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main ()
 { 
    /* Declare variables to store sentence and shift number. 
       i is used for loops, mod temporarily stores input[i] + shift */
    char input[100];
    int mod;
    int shift;
    int i=0 ;
    printf("sentence "); 
    fgets(input, 100, stdin); //fgets stores user input for sentence
                              //while setting a maximum size

    // prompts user to set shift, then mods it to ensure shift stays
    // between 0-26
    printf("\n Number");
    scanf( "%d" , &shift);
    shift = shift % 26;
    //printf( "%d", input[1]);

    /* loops. for loop scans through input, and if statements
     * insure input[i] is an alphabet letter and classify
     * it to the letter's respective case. */
    for ( i =0 ; i < 100 ; i++) { 

        if ( isupper(input[i])) { 
            mod = input[i] + shift; 
            if (mod > 90) { mod -= 26;}
            if (mod < 65) { mod += 26;}
            printf( "%c", mod );  }

        else if( islower(input[i])) {
            mod = input[i] + shift; 
            if (mod > 122) { mod -= 26;}
            if (mod < 97) { mod += 26;}
            printf( "%c", mod );  }
        // my unsuccesful attempt at ignoring empty array spaces
        else if ( input[i] != 000) { 
            printf( "%c", input[i]); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You may want to memset your newly created array with either '\0' (NULL) or some sentinel value.

Comment: @JeffOnsager, `fgets()` will write `\0` at the end by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of string length, you processed 100 char. So instead of looping through 100 char, check with length of string only.

```
for ( i =0 ; i < strlen(input) ; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: I did that but im still getting the same problem ( i changed the last if statement to else if ( input[i] != '\0')

Comment: sorry I’m new, didn’t know that was possible.

Comment: I also started in SO like you only :)